# IOS: AsyncSocket - readData method's invoke mechanism

Tags: ios, invoke, asyncsocket

things are like this:

I used AsyncSocket to connect with server. when the server send some bytes to client `at a time`, app will invoke (`onSocket: didReadData: withTag:`) method; Sometimes, because of the network or other reason, some bytes arrived and the rest bytes arrived later( which means some bytes are delayed).(timeOut = -1)

==================================

Question: how much times did the method(`onSocket: didReadData: withTag:` ) invoke?

1)only one time - it will wait automatically until the bytes are complete？

2)2 or more times - some arrived(invoke), other arrived(invoke)、、、、、like so?

===================================

which thoughts is right? plz geiv me some advice. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK， maybe it's just like this.

Transfer data on TCP:  when you send 1000 bytes at a time, because of lag or other reasons, you may receive the 900 bytes first, but the TCP socket will wait the rest 100 bytes
automatically. So if I use asyncSocket to transfer datas and set the timeout, during these seconds, I don't need to deal with the lagged data.

=========================

**EDIT**

maybe the title of ths question is not appropriate, no one cares the question.

I used the method `-readDataToLength:` instead, first read header.length of data, and parse it, then read the body.length of data;